# Calculate the expression with logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that

$$1-\frac{2}{3}^{\frac{1}{\log_2{\frac{2}{3}}}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

I was trying to calculate it but I failed anytime. 
I would be grateful for help.

Comment: $a^{1/\log_2a}=2^{\log_2a/\log_2a}=2$, so the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formulas:

$$\log_a b = \frac{1}{\log_b a}$$ and $$a^{\log_a b} = b$$.

Comment: Ok, now I get it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^{\frac{1}{\log_2 x}} =  x^{\log_x 2} = 2$ then for $x = \frac{2}{3}$ we get
$$(\frac{2}{3})^{\frac{1}{\log_2 \frac{2}{3}}} = 2$$

So
$$1 - (\frac{2}{3})^{\frac{1}{\log_2 \frac{2}{3}}}  = -1$$